# How to remove certain characters (but not all) before one or more character(s)?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, osx

If I wanted to remove everything before a character (say "("), I would just do something like this `'s/.*(//g'`. Now I want to remove only certain things before a character/some characters, in my case `-` and  before `(` (including space)

I tried a few things but none worked. One example is:

```
sed 's/ *(/(/g'
```

But this only removed the space before and not the others, which makes sense to me when reading the code (it will remove everything between the space and `(`, but I had to try something before asking here), so I tried this: (which also didn't work)

```
sed 's/* (/(/g'
```

But this time I can't see why not. I thought it was because spaces are pretty special characters so I tried with `-` instead (`s/*- (/(/g'` and `s/*-* (/(/g'`) but they didn't work either.

Input:

```
081 379 62 49 (Hems)
081-379-62-49 (Hems)
```

Desired output:

```
0813796249 (Hems)
```

Comment: Please define "didn't work", including any error messages you may have been given.

Comment: Show your input and your desired output.

Comment: @roaima, if there were any error messages I would have said them. Sorry for just assuming, but I thought people would understand I meant that file/words didn't change as I like.

Comment: @glennjackman inputs are either `081 379 62 49 (Hems)` or  `081-379-62-49 (Hems)` and output is `0813796249 (Hems)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove all spaces and dashes immediately before `(`?  Then you need to use a character class or "bracket expression" including space and dash: `[- ]`

```sh
sed -e 's/[- ]*(/(/g'
```

See `man 7 regex` and search for `bracket expression` for more details.

With the input you mentioned (`081 379 62 49 (Hems)` or `081-379-62-49 (Hems)`), you can do it with `awk`:

```sh
awk -F'(' 'BEGIN {OFS=" ("} ; {gsub(/[- ]/,"",$1) ; print}'
```

this tells awk to use `(` as field separator, and then uses the `gsub()` function to remove spaces and dashes from the first field (the phone number).  The Output Field Separator (OFS) is set to `(` (space and `(`) in order to produce the correct output.

e.g.

```sh
echo -e "081 379 62 49 (Hems)\n081-379-62-49 (Hems)" | 
    awk -F'(' 'BEGIN {OFS=" ("} ; {gsub(/[- ]/,"",$1) ; print}'
0813796249 (Hems)
0813796249 (Hems)
```

BTW if there are no spaces or dashes after the phone number (e.g. inside the `(...)`) you could also do this with sed:

```sh
echo -e "081 379 62 49 (Hems)\n081-379-62-49 (Hems)" | 
    sed -e 's/[ -]//g ; s/(/ (/'
```

This strips ALL spaces and dashes from the input line, and then puts one space back immediately before the `(`.  It will uglify the output horrendously if there are multiple words inside the parentheses (comment/name field?)

There's probably some baroquely complicated way of doing it properly in sed by copying the phone number to hold space and modifying it there and then re-inserting it back into the output line, but it's much easier to do it wth awk.

Comment: Not immediately before, but I also meant ` (`
. A space before (.

Comment: if you don't mean immediately before, then what do you mean?  you need to be much clearer in expressing your goal.

Comment: This might be a language issue, because I don't speak English natively, but exactly what do you mean with "immediately before"?  I thought you meant everything before ( but "everything" stops when there's a space.

Comment: Thanks. I really need to learn awk, it seems to be more efficient than sed.

Comment: `sed` is often a lot faster and simpler to use than `awk` but has its limitations....and that's where `awk` or `perl` should be used.

Comment: It's not necessarily more efficient (although it is very efficient), it's syntax is just more familiar for those of us working with C-like languages. I like sed but I don't use it once the sed program starts to get the least bit complicated.

Comment: btw, in English "immediately before" means nothing else before or in between.  so "spaces and dashes immediately before (" means only the spaces and dashes without anything else between them and the `(`.   Just saying "before" is fairly loose and ambiguous, but qualifying it with "immediately" is very precise.

Answer (score 1):

this works with `sed`:

```sh
printf %s\\n '081 379 62 49 (Hems)' \
             '081-379-62-49 (Hems)' |
sed 's/\( ([^)]*)\)\{0,1\}[ -]\{0,1\}/\1/g'
```

---

```
0813796249 (Hems)
0813796249 (Hems)
```

The trick is to let `sed` remove a null string when it isn't removing one of the strings you want it to. In that way the `g`lobal substitution can span the entire pattern space removing a bunch of nothing - *(`\{0,1\}` - 0 or 1 occurrences)* - until it lights on some targeted character and substitutes it away, or replaces it with itself - as it will do for any characters occurring between a pair of `()`.